# EAN Expedia API hotel booking return with error response (authentication)

Tags: php, api, authentication

Currently testing EAN Expedia API with **hotel booking** but it gives authentication error.

[image]

We have tried with **IP authentication** as well as **signature authentication** both return with same error also added IP addresses to our application but did not work.

How to solve this any Idea?